# Assets / S3 and Cloudfront Invalidation Issue

Tags: assets, aws, php7

Recently moved the site to a new server with php7 and configured AWS for assets. When I upload images, I get an error in the console as follows:

```
<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Array to string conversion</p>
<p>Filename: lib/Assets_S3.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 1569</p>

</div><div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: User Warning</p>
<p>Message:  S3::invalidate('XXXXX',Array): [InvalidArgument] Your request contains one or more invalid invalidation paths.</p>
<p>Filename: lib/Assets_S3.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 1570</p>

</div>[{"success":true,"file_id":"22457"}]
```

I'm not sure if the problem is php7, whether it's a configuration issue or whether it's an issue at AWS/Cloudfront.